# Extract lines in File A based on two columns in File B

Tags: awk

I have two files of the same number of column (tab delimited) that look like this

File A:

```
12345    Fish    Apple    7123  
321      Chicken Apple    9912  
661      Ant     Apple    316
```

File B:

```
321      Duck    Orange    9912   
12345    Bird    Orange    7123    
661      Eagle   Orange    34
```

Expected Output:

```
Fiile A_edited    

661    Ant    Apple    316
```

Based on the ID from column 1 and column 4 in File B, if both values appear in column 1 and column 4 of the line in File A, I want to remove the line from File A. I tried using grep to do this, but the two lists are very long, around 66Gb each, so it's still running after a day. Is there any other faster way besides grep that I can do it?

p/s: the number of columns is actually more than 4, shown here only four for simplicity.

```
awk '{print $1 "\t"$4}'B.txt >> B_edited.txt


# Extract the line number in A.txt containing lines where two IDs are present in B_edited.txt
cat B_edited.txt|while read ID1 ID2
do 
    grep -nE "$ID1.*$ID2"  A.txt|cut -c 1 >> LineNumber.txt
done

# Remove duplicates of line numbers 
sort -u LineNumber.txt >> LineNumberUnique.txt

# Output only lines from A.txt where line numbers are not in the list
awk 'FNR == NR { h[$1]; next } !(FNR in h)' LineNumberUnique.txt A.txt >> A_edited.txt
```

I would greatly appreciate any help!

Thanks,
Jen

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk '{k=$1FS$4} NR==FNR{keys[k];next} !(k in keys)' fileB fileA
661      Ant     Apple    316
```

To overwrite `fileA` with the output, just add `> tmp && mv tmp fileA` or use `-i inplace` if you have GNU awk 4.*.